# name 'ClassName' is not defined

Tags: python, class, flask, import, module

My `Flask` project structure looks like this:

```
matcha
    |- matcha
           |- template
              static
              __init__.py
              matcha.py
              user.py
```

**user.py**:

```
class User():
    def __init__(self):
        db = get_db()
    def login(username, password):
        ...
    def register(email, username, firstname, lastname, password):
        ...
```

In **matcha.py** I create a reference of `user` class and on `/login` page I try to call the `login()` method from `user` class file.

```
import os
import sqlite3
from flask import Flask, request, session, g, redirect, url_for, abort, render_template, flash
from . import user

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config.from_object(__name__)
user = User()

...    

@app.route('/login', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def login():
    error = None
    if request.method == 'POST':
        username = request.form['username']
        password = request.form['password']
        if user.login(username, password):
            return redirect(url_for('index'))
        else:
            error = "Invalid username or password"
    return render_template('login.html', error=error)
```

Full Traceback:

```
File "c:\users\stanc\desktop\matcha\matcha\__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
from .matcha import app
File "c:\users\stanc\desktop\matcha\matcha\matcha.py", line 8, in <module>
user = User()
NameError: name 'User' is not defined
```

Comment: post the full traceback.

Comment: maybe try with `user = user.User()` ? (using another name for the instance `user` could be better to not shadow the module `user`)

Answer (score 0):

From what I can see, you're importing the `user` module, not the `User` class written inside `user` module.

Hence, you need to re-write your code as,

```
from .user import User  # change your import to this
user = User()
```

I'm pretty sure that'll solve your problem.